# Why is __init.py__ not importing my views?

Tags: django

My views.py got bloated, and I decided to cut it up into smaller modules by creating a `./views` directory with all the little .py files. Here's what I get when I start the test webserver:

```
File "/path/to/the/app/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_view import my_view 
ImportError: No module named 'my_view'
```

My `./views` directory contains `__init__.py`, which is several lines of:

```
from my_view import my_view
from my_other_view import my_other_view
#etc...
```

`./views/my_view.py` of course looks like:

```
def my_view(request):
    #etc...
```

I've obviously overlooked something, but I can't think what. Can you see the error I have made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess views is not in your `PYTHON_PATH`. Which is right. However this means you should use relative python imports:

```
from .my_view import my_view  # note the leading dot
```

Or absolute import from your project root (which should be in your `PYTHON_PATH`):

```
from myapp.views.my_view import my_view
```